# using local folder into docker container

Tags: docker

Hi I have a windows machine and I installed a docker desktop on it and created a ubuntu container on it.

In docker settings I checked my C: Drive under shared drive option. and I created a folder under /opt named /mydata in this container

Now I run this command:

```
docker my_container_name run -v /Users/john/Documents/DOCKER_FOLDER:/opt/mydata
```

But I don't see the files under DOCKER_FOLDER to be in /opt/mydata folder.

Not sure what I a doing wrong.

Comment: What is the use case? Do you just want to copy a file over? Or do you actually want a "shareable" directory?

Comment: i want a shareable directory

Answer (score 1):

the right command is:

```
docker my_container_name run -v c:/Users/john/Documents/DOCKER_FOLDER:/opt/mydata ls /opt/mydata
```

so you need to specify the volume letter and a command to run

Comment: tried but even after that, it's not showing files under /opt/mydata

Comment: this command works: docker run -t -i -v c:/Users/john/Documents/DOCKER_FOLDER:/opt/mydata  ubuntu /bin/bash but it does not work on VPN